# Coldfusion XML Replace

Tags: xml, replace, coldfusion

Not sure if this is a legitimate operation.

I have an xml document that I am using Coldfusion to read.

If you have the following:

```
 <tag1>
   This is text <tag2>and this is highlighted text</tag2> which is in the middle of more text
 </tag1>
```

Can I put all of tag1 into a variable and do a replace on the variable to change the tag2 into html with a class so that it comes out highlighted?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Well that's not valid XML for a start. Should the second `<tag2>` be `</tag2>`? If so, pls update the question. Yer probably better off not treating this as XML, and just do a string replacement? Or perhaps look at what JSOUP (http://jsoup.org/) has to offer in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Turn the tag1 node and all of its children tags into a string.

```
 <cfset x = #tag1.xmlChildren[x]#>
```

Replace the tag2 with the need html tag.

```
 <cfset x = #Replace(x,"<tag2>","&lt;mark&gt;","ALL")#>
 <cfset x = #Replace(x,"</tag2>","&lt;/mark&gt;","ALL")#>
```

Parse string back to xml.

```
 <cfset x = XmlParse(#x#)>
```

Out put the parsed xml.

```
 <cfoutput>#x.tag1.xmlText#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tag1>
    <![CDATA[
        This is text <tag2>and this is highlighted text</tag2> which is in the middle of more text
    ]]>
</tag1>
```

This here will add it as a string without the need to escape anything. It will be treated as a string and not part of the XML structure.